# Where does one get Visual Source Safe 2005?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I would like to install VSS 2005 so I can work on a project that is stored under it. Does anyone have any idea where the VSS 2005 client can be obtained? It does not appear to be on my VS2005 install disc (although that is for Team Suite). I cannot get any help from Google. I have an MSDN license (AA edition) but it doesn't seem to be there. This is a real product right?

Just to clarify preemptively based on some of the discussions I see on Google when I search for things like "VSS 2005," I am aware of the flaws in VSS and I still need to get it working; I am not interested in converting the project to Subversion; I am not able to transfer it to TFS; I am not able to upgrade the project to VS2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two places, both from Microsoft:

- [Microsoft Store](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Microsoft-Visual-SourceSafe-2005/product/25994351) ($549.00)
- [MSDN Subscriber Downloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/securedownloads/default.aspx) (Developer Tools > SourceSafe)

Answer (score 5):

So, this is an old thread but occasionally still relevant.  I'm adding an answer in case anyone comes across it in a google search.

If you have a copy of VSS 2005 installed on another machine but can't find the installation media, you can just copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Source Safe` to your local machine.  It will run just fine.  Launch `ssexp.exe` and have at it.

Comment: For Visual Studio integration you need to export 2 registry keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/how-to-install-a-source-control-plug-in?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from MSDN, I just looked it is there...see screenshot below

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's not in the AA license provided by IEEE, unfortunately. That seems like it would be for the server install. Is there not a free client tool somewhere?